# Combining list and get

Tags: r, list, get

How can I combine list and get? my goal is to run an operation like

```
compare <- list(get(variables[1:length(variables)]))
```

I have a vector named `variables` where each coordinate is one of my variables in .GlobalEnv. This is my vector

```
variables <- c("var1","var2",...,"varN")
```

I also have each variable in memory. So that if I run var1 (or any other) I get

```
> var1
[1] 0.5      
[2] 0.7                           
[3] 0.9                                      
[4] 0.3                   
[5] 0.1
```

Then I can run, for example, `list(var1,var10,var100)` but `list(get(variables[1:length(variables)]))` does the same as `list(var1,var1)`

Comment: you could `lapply(variables,get)`

Comment: or simply `mget(variables)`

Comment: whoa... the more I learn the more awkward my ideas goes
thanks a lot !!